# Galaxy Editor change map lighting?

Tags: starcraft-2, galaxy-editor

Is it possible to change the global lighting setup of a Starcraft II custom map?

Comment: Consider also asking this on gamedev.stackexchange.com (as they've decided that map-editor questions are within their scope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! It's under Window > Lighting.

Comment: You're perfectly entitled (encouraged even) to accept your own answers on questions that the community have been unable to answer.

Comment: @Lee: I had to wait since there's a 24 (48?) hour moratorium on selecting your own answer after you make it. :)